# Convergence of a geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

so I'm working on Laurent Series, and got into trouble calculating such series. The problem is taken from here (P. 2, example 2.3): http://sym.lboro.ac.uk/resources/Handout-Laurent.pdf

Find $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z+2)}$ when $1 \lt |z-1| \lt 3$.

So we set $w=z-1$ so $1 \lt |w| \lt 3$ , eventually reaching to $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1-(-w)}-\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{1-(-\frac{w}{3})})$. As for the series $\frac{1}{1-(-w)}$, we see it converges when $|w| \lt 1$. So let's manipulate it, and get $\frac {1}{w} \frac{1}{1-(-\frac{1}{w})}$, which indeed converges when $|w| \gt 1$. So by geometric series we get: $\frac {1}{w} \frac{1}{1-(-\frac{1}{w})}=\frac {1}{w} \Sigma _{n=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n}{w^n}=\Sigma _{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n}{w^n}$

So at the solved example in the link, there is a use in something called 'modified geometric sequence', with a formula for when $|w|>1$, which I haven't studied. In the solved example in the link, they reach the same result for the first series, only with a negative to it.

Where is my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: Your mistake is simply forgetting a minus sign when doing two steps at once. $$\frac{1}{w}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{w^n} = \frac{1}{w}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{w^{n-1}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{w^n}.$$

Comment: Ah right! Thanks!